# Executing a series of methods in a chain in a specific order

Tags: javascript, constructor

Let's assume we have a constructor function and its prototype:

```
function Person(name){
  this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype = {
  setSex: function(sex){
    this.sex = sex;
    return this;
  },
  setEyes: function(color){
    this.eyes = color;
    return this;
  },
  setHair: function(color){
    this.hair = color;
    return this;
  }  
}
```

In order to create a person and build their features, we use method chaining, like so:

```
var person1 = new Person('John');    
person1.setEyes('Blue').setHair('Brown').setSex('male')
```

Except that the framework I'm using frustratingly requires me to create the `sex` **first**, then the `eyes` and then `hair` (and specifically in that order). I think it's stupid and unreasonable to expect that methods be sequentially ordered, but I have no choice. So, I'm trying to build a function that is somewhat more forgiving and takes the (potentially unordered) list of methods and builds them sequentially in the background.

Problem is, I wouldn't even know where to start here.

I was thinking instead pushing results into an object after each method in the chain executes, and then fire off a series of functions that  adhere to a pre-defined order(which could look something like this):

```
person1 = {
  hair: 'brown',
  sex: 'male',
  eyes: 'blue',
}    

var orderOfMethods = ['sex','eyes','hair'];

orderOfMethods.forEach(function(){
  if(currentValue in person1){
    //do that function
  } 
})
```

But this seems like a massively convoluted solution. Any ideas?

Comment: which framework are you using?

Comment: Would a `setAttributes({hair: 'brown', sex: 'male', eyes: 'blue'})` method that internally processes the attributes in predefined order be OK, or are you asking for a way to actually chain separate methods in any order and have them magically queue the changes behind the scenes to execute in the correct order?

Comment: I'm using p5.js. In that framework, when drawing shapes, I need to specify the rotation of the canvas BEFORE I define a shape within that canvas. I'm trying to build a little plugin that makes that unnecessary.

Comment: @nnnnnn I'm not sure I follow... can you expand on that?

Comment: Well the first thing I mentioned is like Lux's answer (but I'd add some if tests to only call the relevant methods). But are you asking how to have code like `person1.setEyes('Blue').setHair('Brown').setSex('male')` that behind the scenes does the updates to those properties in the correct order? To do that you'd need to have each method add the update to a queue rather than doing it immediately, then have some way to trigger execution of whatever's in the queue (at which point it could be sorted into the right order).

Comment: Why do you think that the framework "requires me to create the sex first, then the eyes and then hair". I haven't seen anything yet that wants functions inside it to be called in specific order to set the properties, and even those are user-defined functions?

Comment: It actually does... rendering a shape on the screen and having it `translate` (move) **requires** the `translate` function to preceed the `rect` function.

Comment: It's my understanding that things like Processing, Nodebox, and P5 are state machines, which means the order of operations is important. In most cases rotate.draw is different than draw.rotate. I suspect this is why they enforce a chaining order.

Answer (score 1):

Um, why not just have a function that calls the functions in the right order and takes the params as an object?

```
function createPerson(params) {
  return (new Person())
    .setSex(params.sex)
    .setEyes(params.eyes)
    .setHair(params.hair);
}
```

then you can just do `createPerson({ hair: 'blue', eyes: 'brown', sex: 'male' })`.

---

If you *really* need a chain of methods, just create a dummy object with that methods, that store the params away, and later have some kind of `run` function to apply all the calls. Assume this:

```
function makeChainBuilder(...funcs) {
    const builder = { __params__: {} };
    funcs.forEach(func => {
        builder[func] = function(...args) {
            this.__params__[func] = args;
        };
    });

    builder.run = target => {
        funcs.forEach(func => {
            const args = this.__params__[func];
            if(args) {
                target = target[func](...params);
            }
        });

        return target;
    }
}
```

This can be used like `makeChainBuilder('setSex', 'setEyes', 'setHair')`, and return a `builder` object which, if you call one of the methods just stores the params away. later when you can `run` and pass a target, it will call the same functions with the stored params but in the specified order on that target object:

```
builder.setEyes('brown');
builder.setHair('blue');
builder.setSex('male');
builder.run(new Person()); // this will apply (new Person()).setSex('male').setEyes('brown').setHair('blue');
```

Comment: This does solve the problem, but I was hoping to do it with a series of methods in a chain. Principally, I want to understand how I can make the above problem work.

Comment: @Modermo - if doing it via a series of methods, what happens if you don't include `.setSex()` in the series? Would the rest of the changes just sit there queued and waiting for a future call to `.setSex()`, or do you need to add a `.execQueue()` function that just executes whatever is currently in the chain in the correct order?

Comment: No, they would not sit there queued i.e.  if `.setSex()` isn't invoked, then the `eyes` and `hair` would execute on their own but it would have a meaningless consequence on the interface. We would need specifically an `.execQueue()` that as you said just executes whatever is currently in the chain in the correct order?

Comment: What do you mean? Well, if you want to execute all functions no matter if you called them on the builder, just remove the `if(args) {`!